# Joystick connect WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть приложение на WPF заказчик хочет управлять программой джойстиком типа "joystick cyborg x" (без клавиатуры и мышки)

пробовал подключать по типу https://habrahabr.ru/post/124851/ - не вышло. 
п.с. драйвера на ноут установлены.

Может кто то сталкивался - подскажите как это сделать.